# How to move part of the string after exact word to another field in logstash?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Let's imagine I have log file like the following:

```
My custom exception ST: java.lang.RuntimeException: Text of this dummy err.
```

My final goal is to put everything after `ST:` to new field ST called and remove `ST:`.

I'm trying to use the pattern, but it doesn't work.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<newField>(?<=ST)(?s)(.*$))" }
}
```

Comment: Как, помогло моё решение?

Answer (score 0):

Grok is [based on Oniguruma](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_regular_expressions) regex library. To make `.` match any char with an [Oniguruma regex](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Docs-for-Oniguruma-Regular-Expressions-(RE.txt)), you need to pass `(?m)` inline modifier, not `(?s)` (as in PCRE and some other regex engines).

By placing `(?<=ST)` positive lookahead inside the named capturing group, you require `ST` to appear immediately before the current location, but you have `ST` and a colon right after, and then a space. It makes sense to **just move `ST:` out of the named group**:

```
"(?m)ST: (?<newField>.*)"
 ^^^^^^^^
```

The `ST:` and space will get matched and consumed, `newField` group will hold the rest of string in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specific regex like that:

```
^My custom exception ST: %{GREEDYDATA:ST}
```

Or a more generric one:

```
%{GREEDYDATA} \bST\b: %{GREEDYDATA:ST}
```

Always try to use specific regex.